# Wht can't I receive POWER_CONNECTED action?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

I am learning Android. I dynamically register my custom broadcast receiver `CustomBroadcastreceiver` in `MainActivity.java` with below codes:

```
package com.example.bob.broadcastcounterback;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PackageManager packageManager;
    private ComponentName componentName;
    private CustomBroadcastreceiver customReceiver;
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        componentName = new ComponentName(this,CustomBroadcastreceiver.class);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.countText);

        customReceiver = new CustomBroadcastreceiver(textView);

        IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        mIntentFilter.addAction("com.example.bob.broadcastcounter");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).
                registerReceiver(customReceiver,mIntentFilter);

//        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(customReceiver,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

//        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
//                componentName,
//                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
//                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
//        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
//                componentName,
//                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
//                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("DESTORY CALLED:","destroy");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(customReceiver);
    }

    public void sendBroadcast(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.bob.broadcastcounter");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

CustomBroadcastreceiver.java:

```
package com.example.bob.broadcastcounterback;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private int count = 0;

    private static final String ACTION_MY_BRODACAST = "com.example.bob.broadcastcounter";

    public CustomBroadcastreceiver(){
        super();
    }

    public CustomBroadcastreceiver(TextView mTextView){
        this();
        this.mTextView = mTextView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        String intentString = intent.getAction();


        switch (intentString){
            case Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED:
                Log.d("BroadcastReceiver:",mTextView.toString());
                mTextView.setText("power connected!");
//                mTextView.setText(++count);
                break;
            case ACTION_MY_BRODACAST :
                mTextView.setText("Custombroadcast Received!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way I can receive the `ACTION_MY_BRODACAST` broadcast everytime I press the button whose `onClick` is `sendBroadcast(View view)`. But when I plugin or un-plugin the USB cable, nothing will happen. Then I choose to register the broadcastreceiver in `AndroidManinfest.xml`:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".CustomBroadcastreceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This time I don't know what happens: every time I plugin the charging line the app just immediately crashes and returns. I even cant see the logcat in Android Studio. To know what really happens I add `Thread.sleep(5000)` to the `onReceive()` method:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        String intentString = intent.getAction();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            Log.e("Broadcastcounterback:",e.toString());
        }



        switch (intentString){
            case Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED:
                Log.d("BroadcastReceiver:",mTextView.toString());
                mTextView.setText("power connected!");
//                mTextView.setText(++count);
                break;
            case ACTION_MY_BRODACAST :
                mTextView.setText("Custombroadcast Received!");
                break;
        }
    }
```

This time when I click the button that sends my custom broadcast, the `mTextView` will show `Custombroadcast Received!` after a 5 seconds break. When I plugin the charging line , after 5 seconds I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.view.View.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.bob.broadcastcounterback.CustomBroadcastreceiver.onReceive(CustomBroadcastreceiver.java:41)
```

This shows that `mTextView` is null when I receive the POWER_CONNECTED action. Why? I instantiated the customReceiver with `customReceiver = new CustomBroadcastreceiver(textView);`
, so the mTextView shouldn't be null and actually the `ACTION_MY_BRODACAST` action will trigger the mTextView to show correct text without any error.
At last, my two questions:

1 we can only receive the POWER_CONNECTED action with static registration with a broadcastreceiver?

2 Why would the error happen?

Comment: 1.) A Receiver registered with `LocalBroadcastManager` will not get that broadcast. You need to register that Receiver on a `Context`, like your `Activity`. 2.) Statically registered Receiver classes will be instantiated by the system as needed. Those instances will not have had the `mTextView` field set.

Comment: @Mike M Thank you point this and I got it now. But another error happends when I uncomment `packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
          PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);`

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class com.example.bob.broadcastcounterback.CustomBroadcastreceiver does not exist in com.example.bob.broadcastcounterback`

Comment: It's not clear what your current setup is. Are you doing this with the dynamically registered Receiver instance; i.e., `registerReceiver()`? Or the statically registered class; i.e., the `<receiver>` in the manifest? The `setComponentEnabledSetting()` method is for manifest components. If you don't have the `<receiver>` currently, it will throw that Exception.

Comment: Thank you, You are right.  I comment the `<receiver>` tag so this Exception thrown. I will close this question.

Comment: If you want to make your comment as an answer, I will accept that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` broadcast is a system broadcast. `LocalBroadcastManager` handles only broadcasts sent with `LocalBroadcastManager`, so your Receiver instance registered with that will not get the `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` broadcast. You would need to register your Receiver instance on a `Context`, like your `Activity`.
2. The `<receiver>` element in the manifest statically registers the Receiver *class*, not any existing *instance*. That class is then instantiated by the system as needed, and none of those instances will have the `TextView` field set. If you want to update an `Activity` from a statically registered Receiver class, you would need to use some other mechanism; e.g., `Intent`s, `LocalBroadcastManager`, some other event bus, etc.

---

I would also mention that the `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` broadcast is not on [the list of implicit broadcast exemptions for Android 8.0 and above](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), so if your `targetSdkVersion` is 26+, you cannot receive that broadcast with a statically registered Receiver, starting with Oreo.